# convert from make to cmake

Tags: macos, cmake, gnu-make

I've followed tutorials and looked at examples but I still can not get a build working repo with make to compile after converting to  cmake on a MacBook Pro.  The commented out code in the cmake file combines the efforts to reference other stack exchange comments.

**Makefile**

```
# tool macros
CC := g++
# TODO: Get rid of -Wunused-command-line-argument warnings
CCFLAGS := -lcurl -std=c++11
DBGFLAGS := -g
CCOBJFLAGS := $(CCFLAGS) -c

# path macros
BIN_PATH := bin
OBJ_PATH := obj
SRC_PATH := src
DBG_PATH := debug

# compile macros
TARGET_NAME := light-thing
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    TARGET_NAME := $(addsuffix .exe,$(TARGET_NAME))
endif
TARGET := $(BIN_PATH)/$(TARGET_NAME)
TARGET_DEBUG := $(DBG_PATH)/$(TARGET_NAME)

# src files & obj files
SRC := $(foreach x, $(SRC_PATH), $(wildcard $(addprefix $(x)/*,.c*)))
OBJ := $(addprefix $(OBJ_PATH)/, $(addsuffix .o, $(notdir $(basename $(SRC)))))
OBJ_DEBUG := $(addprefix $(DBG_PATH)/, $(addsuffix .o, $(notdir $(basename $(SRC)))))

# clean files list
DISTCLEAN_LIST := $(OBJ) \
                  $(OBJ_DEBUG)
CLEAN_LIST := $(TARGET) \
              $(TARGET_DEBUG) \
              $(DISTCLEAN_LIST)

# default rule
default: makedir all

# non-phony targets
$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJ)

$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o: $(SRC_PATH)/%.c*
    $(CC) $(CCOBJFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(DBG_PATH)/%.o: $(SRC_PATH)/%.c*
    $(CC) $(CCOBJFLAGS) $(DBGFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(TARGET_DEBUG): $(OBJ_DEBUG)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(DBGFLAGS) $(OBJ_DEBUG) -o $@

# phony rules
.PHONY: makedir
makedir:
    @mkdir -p $(BIN_PATH) $(OBJ_PATH) $(DBG_PATH)

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGET)

.PHONY: debug
debug: $(TARGET_DEBUG)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @echo CLEAN $(CLEAN_LIST)
    @rm -f $(CLEAN_LIST)

.PHONY: distclean
distclean:
    @echo CLEAN $(CLEAN_LIST)
    @rm -f $(DISTCLEAN_LIST)
```

**current CMakeLists**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(hue_console VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)
option(huecon_BUILD_TESTS OFF)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -Wextra -fpermissive -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-comment")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
# set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
# # Fix behavior of CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD when targeting macOS.
# if (POLICY CMP0025)
#   cmake_policy(SET CMP0025 NEW)
# endif ()

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF) 
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)  
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF) 
#find_package(Boost 1.45.0 COMPONENTS property_tree) 
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
if(Boost_FOUND)
  include_directories(include)
  include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}) 
  file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")
  #target_link_libraries(progname ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
else(Boost_FOUND)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find the boost required.")
endif()

find_package(CURL)
set(requiredlibs)
if(CURL_FOUND)
  include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  set(requiredlibs ${requiredlibs} ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
else(CURL_FOUND)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find the CURL library / dev files.")
endif(CURL_FOUND)

add_executable(hue_console 
  ${SOURCES})
```

**cmake output**

```
mreff555@Dans-MBP build % cmake ..
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 13.1.6.13160021
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefaul
t.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Boost: /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.78.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.78.0")
-- Found CURL: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.dylib (found version "7.79.1")
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/mreff555/src/hue-api/build
```

**cmake -> make output**

```
mreff555@Dans-MBP build % make
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target hue_console
[ 10%] Linking CXX executable hue_console
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_curl_easy_cleanup", referenced from:
      Command::get(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in command.cpp.o
      Command::post(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in comman
d.cpp.o
      Command::put(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in command
.cpp.o
  "_curl_easy_init", referenced from:
      Command::get(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in command.cpp.o
      Command::post(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in comman
d.cpp.o
      Command::put(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in command
.cpp.o
  "_curl_easy_perform", referenced from:
      Command::get(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in command.cpp.o
      Command::post(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in comman
d.cpp.o
      Command::put(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in command
.cpp.o
  "_curl_easy_setopt", referenced from:
      Command::get(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in command.cpp.o
      Command::post(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in comman
d.cpp.o
      Command::put(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in command
.cpp.o
  "_curl_easy_strerror", referenced from:
      Command::get(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in command.cpp.o
      Command::post(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in comman
d.cpp.o
  "_curl_global_cleanup", referenced from:
      Command::~Command() in command.cpp.o
  "_curl_global_init", referenced from:
      Command::Command(std::__1::shared_ptr<Config>) in command.cpp.o
  "_curl_slist_append", referenced from:
      Command::put(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in command
.cpp.o
  "_curl_slist_free_all", referenced from:
      Command::put(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in command
.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [hue_console] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/hue_console.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: You forgot to **link** with Curl, using `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: Your makefile has thist: `CCFLAGS := -lcurl`.  This is not reflected anywhere in your cmake file.  If you look at the error output, it's clear that the problem is that the linker cannot find the curl methods you're calling, so there should be not much mystery about where you need to look.